# JWPlayer controlbar error when playing HLS file

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I have a jwplayer set up that plays an `mp4` file as it should. With this same setup using an `hls` file, the controlbar 'sticks' to the player and does not disappear when the user's cursor is out of the picture.

Here is an example of the the player with two different files: the HLS file on top which has the controlbar bug, and the mp4 file on the bottom, which works normally: http://streaming2.cinely.com/title/1

Here is my jwplayer setup:

```
playerInstance.setup({
    skin: "glow",
    icons: false,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    sources: sources,
    controlbar: 'bottom',
    plugins: {
        'overlay': {
            data: data['Data'],
            beforeOverlayUrl: '/static/plugins/overlay/templates/beforeOverlay.html',
            afterOverlayUrl: '/static/plugins/overlay/templates/afterOverlay.html'
        }
    },
    // file: 'http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus.mp4',
});
```

Why is this issue occurring and how would I fix it for an hls file?

Comment: That bug really is weird. It works as long as you don't hover the controls (just moving in and out of the video works), but if you do, it screws it up. Full screen is also not working on the HLS one. Since you have a paid membership, ask them for support, they need to know about these bugs to fix them..

Comment: @blex -- thanks for the feedback, I never noticed there was a full-screen bug as well until you mentioned it as well. I contacted their customer support about this. Do you think this would be an issue with the HLS encode itself, or in the jwplayer?

Comment: More feedback - in FF 39, there's no video, only sound (absolute latest Flash installed). The "stuck" controlbar afflicts all browsers, however.

Comment: @MisterNeutron would you happen to know if this is more related to the jwplayer or the hls file? If it'd be helpful for me to send you the `hls` main file, let me know and I can post that as well.

Comment: Not sure. HLS support with Flash is a bit "hit or miss" these days. If the HLS displays properly in browsers that support it natively, I'd have to assume that the stream itself is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a missing declaration in the `HLS` manifest file. This was causing jwplayer to act screwy and adding this in seemed to be the root cause of the other issues:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
```

The second line is needed to properly play multiple audio files. Here is an example of a proper manifest file including multiple audio tracks from the jwplayer site:

Video: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1761348-multiple-audio-renditions
Manifest: http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/eleph-audio/playlist.m3u8

Comment: Glad you got it, thanks for sharing the answer to this.